# Add new cell row on Clicking Button which is in cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have subclassed `UITableViewCell` with custom class. And added some outlets to it. Now I want to get the `IBAction` on button inside my cells. How i can define the IBAction inside `ViewContoller` itself.

Answer (score 2):

```
// In cellForRowAtIndexpath

cell.yourButton.tag=indexPath.row;
button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonHandler:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)


func buttonHandler(sender:UIButton!)
{
    if(sender.tag==0){
         println("Button at row 0")
    }
    else if(sender.tag==1){
       println("Button at row 1")
    }
}
```

Comment: With this approach, the button no longer remains a part of the cell but becomes the part of the view controller

Answer (score 2):

If you add the handler in the view controller, then it will break the MVC pattern. The event on view should be handled within the view itself. However, you can create a delegate for your view and invoke the method that you want to from your button action handler itself.

Also, since in your XIB, you will be specifying the outlet class as your UITableViewCell subclass. So, only this subclass will be able to handle your events.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create outlets of a cell in a view controller class as different instances of a cell are created dynamically which indeed requires different outlets connections for each of them.
What you can do is to create a delegate of the custom cell class and in the method cellForRowAtIndex where you dequeue cell set it to be the view controller instance.
Then when the action of the button is triggered you can call the delegate method and transfer the control to the view controller instance.

Note: Please share your scenario for further help
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Other approach is you can declare a block in UITAbleviewCell class like:

```
 var block_CheckBox: (() -> ())!
```

Suppose button have a IBOutlet Action like:

```
 @IBAction func didActButton_CheckBoxClicked(_ sender: AnyObject)
    {
        if block_CheckBox != nil{
            block_CheckBox()
        }
    }
```

We called the block when button is pressed.

In `Controller` class, you can define the block as:

```
 cell.block_CheckBox = {
            ()in
            //Do required action
        }
```

The block will only call when you press the button.

Comment: could you please give me the objective C version

Comment: @Saranjith Please read this tutorial to use blocks in Objective-c. http://www.appcoda.com/objective-c-blocks-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can create any tap handler you want.

```
#define handle_tap(view, delegate, selector) do {\
view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;\
[view addGestureRecognizer: [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:delegate action:selector]];\
} while(0)
```

later in your code:

```
SEL sel = @selector(actionOfMine:);
    handle_tap(btnbck, self, sel);
```

to handle it:

```
-(void) actionOfMine:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    UIView * button = (UIView *) recognizer.view;
    int i = (int)button.tag;
//...
}
```

Comment: Please don't use macro if a plain C function can achieve the same thing.

Comment: Adding a macro will unnecessarily complicate the things. Also, such approach will break the MVC pattern.

Comment: Please, describe more detailed your meaning. This implementation works, easy-to-use, no memory leaks. I've not found any disadvantange of such solution. Futhemore, this is can really help to add any tap programatically.

Comment: @Saranjith , approve if it was helpful.